# Does vision really improve by wearing spectacles?

Tags: diet, eye, vision

I had a discussion with friends that. One of them who had an eye power of -0.75 has improved and now has an eye power of -0.50 . This happens because he is always wearing spectacles and has a good diet.

Is it really true that spectacles can improve vision? Please provide a full explanation if possible.

Comment: It seems like you have 2 questions, 1: Can corrective lenses lead to an improvement in eye sight, and 2: Can diet improve eye sight?  Are those the two questions or do you mean is there an advantage to the combination?